# Dropping number of columns (ending with same letter) from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I want to drop all columns ending with "T". I used for loop which works. I want to know is there any better way. My code-

```
for column in df.columns:
    if column[-1]== "T":
        df.drop(columns = column, inplace = True)
```

Comment: hi! Is any one of the answers below working? If so & if you wish, you might consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) one of them to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so they can be improved (or removed altogether)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df=df.drop(df.filter(regex='T$').columns,axis=1)
```

OR

```
df=df.loc[:,~df.columns.str.endswith('T')]
```

OR

```
df=df.loc[:,~(df.columns.str[-1]=='T')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of drop columns, keep columns you want:

```
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.endswith('T')]
```